# How to chown filesystem element by device:inode pair in perl, or a better solution

Tags: linux, perl, unix, posix

I have a relatively complex perl script which is walking over a filesystem and storing a list of updated ownership, then going over that list and applying the changes.  I'm doing this in order to update changed UIDs.  Because I have several situations where I'm swapping user a's and user b's UIDs, I can't just say "everything which is now 1 should be 2 and everything which is 2 should be 1", as it's also possible that this script could be interrupted, and the system would be left in a completely busted, pretty much unrecoverable state outside of "restore from backup and start over".  Which would pretty much suck.

To avoid that problem, I do the two-pas approach above, creating a structure like $changes->{path}->\%c, where c has attributes line newuid, olduid, newgid, and olduid.  I then freeze the hash, and once it's written to disk, I read the hash back in and start making changes.  This way, if I'm interrupted, I can check to see if the frozen hash exists or not, and just start applying changes again if it does.

The drawback is that sometimes a changing user has literally millions of files, often with very long paths.  This means I'm storing a lot of really long strings as hash keys, and I'm running out of memory sometimes.  So, I've come up with two options.  The one relevant to this question is to instead store the elements as device:inode pairs.  That'd be way more space-efficient, and would uniquely identify filesystem elements.  The drawback is that I haven't figured out a particularly efficient way to either get a device-relative path from the inode, or to just apply the stat() changes I want to the inode.  Yes, I could do another find, and for each file do a lookup against my stored list of devices and inodes to see if a change is needed or not.  But if there's a perl-accessible system call - which is portable across HP-UX, AIX, and Linux - from which I can directly just say "on this device make these changes to this inode", it'd be notably better from a performance perspective.

I'm running this across several thousand systems, some of which have filesystems in the petabyte range, having trillions of files.  So, while performance may not make much of a differece on my home PC, it's actually somewhat significant in this scenario. :)  That performance need, BTW, is why I really don't want to do the other option - which would be to bypass the memory problem by just tie-ing a hash to a disk-based file.  And is why I'd rather do more work to avoid having to traverse the whole filesystem a second time.

Alternate suggestions which could reduce memory consumption are, of course, also welcome. :)  My requirement is just that I need to record both the old and new UID/GID values, so I can back the changes out / validate changes / update files restored from backups taken prior to the cleanup date. I've considered making /path/to/file look like ${changes}->{root}->{path}->{to}->{file}, but that's a lot more work to traverse, and I dont know that it'll really save me enough memory space to resolve my problem.  Collapsing the whole thing to ->{device}->{inode} makes it basically just the size of two integers rather than N characters, which is *substatial* for any path longer than, say, 2 chars. :)

Comment: The more I thought about it, the more that sounded likely.  And, given that I have five or six filesystems on 25+ architectures to deal with, that probably would be more trouble than it's worth.  What I could probably do is just run the find a second time, and if the inode matches one I'm looking for, change it.  But that slows the whole process down a bunch in the common case where I only have a few changes to make; I like the direct access behavior way better. :/

Comment: Perhaps I could take a hybrid approach, and if I find that my memory structure has exceeded a certain threshold, switch over to storing device:inode.  Or maybe I could switch to a 2-level hash and store paths as device:/path/relative/to/mountpoint; that might compress things down just enough to save me, but would add the minor complexity of enumerating all mountpoints (which I could do in the first pass - map a device to a mountpoint, and freeze that with the rest of the changefile)

Comment: Or maybe if I store the device->mountpoint mapping, then I could limit my second-pass find to just the given device, which would probably be not-so-bad performance-wise, assuming a reasonable distribution of files across mountpoints (which is probably a bad assumption). :)

Answer (score 1):

### Simplified idea

When I mentioned streaming, **I didn't mean uncontrolled**. A database journal (e.g.) is also written in streaming mode, for comparison.

Also note, that the statement that you '*cannot afford to sort even a single subdirectory*' directly contradicts the use of a Perl hash to store the same info (I won't blame you if you don't have the CS background).

So here is a really simple illustration of what you *could* do. Note that every step on the way is streaming, repeatable and logged.

```
# export SOME_FIND_OPTIONS=...?
find $SOME_FIND_OPTIONS -print0 | ./generate_script.pl > chownscript.sh

# and then
sh -e ./chownscript.sh
```

An example of generate_script.pl (obviously, adapt it to your needs:)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/="\0";
while (<>)
{
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,$atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat;

    # demo purpose, silly translation:
    my ($newuid, $newgid) = ($uid+1000, $gid+1000);

    print "./chmod.pl $uid:$gid $newuid:$newgid '$_'\n"
}
```

You could have a system dependent implementation of chmod.pl (this helps to reduce complexity and therefore: risk):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $oldown = shift;
my $newown = shift;
my $path   = shift;

($oldown and $newown and $path) or die "usage: $0 <uid:gid> <newuid:newgid> <path>";

my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,$atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat $path;

die "file not found: $path" unless $ino;
die "precondition failed" unless ($oldown eq "$uid:$gid");

($uid, $gid) = split /:/, $newown;

chown $uid, $gid, $path or die "unable to chown: $path"
```

This will allow you to restart when things bork midway, it will even allow you to hand-pick exceptions if necessary. You can save the scripts so you'll have accountability. I've done a reasonable stab at making the scripts operate safely. However, this is obviously just a starting point. Most importantly, I do not deal with filesystem crossings, symbolic links, sockets, device nodes where you might want to pay attention to them.

---

original response follows:

### Ideas

Yeah, if performance is the issue, do it in C

Do not do persistent logging for the whole filesystem (by the way, why the need to keep them in a single hash? streaming output is your friend there)

Instead, log completed runs per directory. You could easily break the mapping up in steps:

```
 user A: 1  -> 99
 user B: 2  -> 1
 user A: 99 -> 2
```

### Ownify - what I use (*code*)

As long as you can reserve a range for temporary uids/guids like the 99 there won't be any risk on having to restart (not any *more* than doing this transnumeration on a live filesystem, anyway).

You could start from this nice tidbit of C code (which admittedly is not very highly optmized):

```
// vim: se ts=4 sw=4 et ar aw 
//
// make: g++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 ownify.cpp -o ownify 
//
// Ownify: ownify -h
//

#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

/* old habits die hard. can't stick to pure C ... */
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define do_stat(a,b)        lstat(a,b)
#define do_chown(a,b,c)     lchown(a,b,c)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// logic declarations
//
void ownify(struct stat& file)
{
//  if (S_ISLNK(file.st_mode))
//      return;
    switch (file.st_uid)
    {
#if defined(PASS1)
        case 1:  file.st_uid = 99; break;
        case 99: fputs(err, "Unexpected existing owned file!"); exit(255);
#elif defined(PASS2)
        case 2:  file.st_uid = 1;  break;
#elif defined(PASS3)
        case 99: file.st_uid = 1;  break;
#endif
    }
    switch (file.st_gid) // optionally map groups as well
    {
#if defined(PASS1)
#elif defined(PASS2)
#elif defined(PASS3)
#endif
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// driver
//
static unsigned int changed = 0, skipped = 0, failed  = 0;
static bool dryrun = false;

void process(const char* const fname)
{
    struct stat s;
    if (0==do_stat(fname, &s))
    {
        struct stat n = s;
        ownify(n);

        if ((n.st_uid!=s.st_uid) || (n.st_gid!=s.st_gid))
        {
            if (dryrun || 0==do_chown(fname, n.st_uid, n.st_gid))
                printf("%u\tchanging owner %i:%i '%s'\t(was %i:%i)\n", 
                        ++changed,
                        n.st_uid, n.st_gid, 
                        fname, 
                        s.st_uid, s.st_gid);
            else 
            {
                failed++;
                int e = errno;
                fprintf(stderr, "'%s': cannot change owner %i:%i (%s)\n", 
                        fname, 
                        n.st_uid, n.st_gid, 
                        strerror(e));
            }
        }
        else
            skipped++;
    } else
    {
        int e = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "'%s': cannot stat (%s)\n", fname, strerror(e));
        failed++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    switch(argc)
    {   
        case 0: //huh?
        case 1: break;
        case 2:
            dryrun = 0==strcmp(argv[1],"-n") || 
                0==strcmp(argv[1],"--dry-run");
            if (dryrun)
                break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "Illegal arguments" << std::endl;
            std::cout << 
                argv[0] << " (Ownify): efficient bulk adjust of owner user:group for many files\n\n"
                           "Goal: be flexible and a tiny bit fast\n\n" 
                           "Synopsis:\n"
                           "    find / -print0 | ./ownify -n 2>&1 | tee ownify.log\n\n"
                           "Input:\n"
                           "    reads a null-delimited stream of filespecifications from the\n"
                           "    standard input; links are _not_ dereferenced.\n\n"
                           "Options:\n"
                           "    -n/--dry-run    - test run (no changes)\n\n"
                           "Exit code:\n"
                           "    number of failed items" << std::endl;
            return 255;
    }

    std::string fname("/dev/null");
    while (std::getline(std::cin, fname, '\0'))
        process(fname.c_str());

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: completed with %u skipped, %u changed and %u failed%s\n", 
            argv[0], skipped, changed, failed, dryrun?" (DRYRUN)":"");

    return failed;
}
```

Note that this comes with quite a few safety measures

- paranoia check in first pass (check no fiels with reserved uid exists)
- ability to change behaviour of `do_stat` and `do_chown` with regards to links
- a **`--dry-run`** option (to observe what *would be done*) **`-n`**

The program will gladly tell you how to use it with `ownify -h`:

```
./ownify (Ownify): efficient bulk adjust of owner user:group for many files

Goal: be flexible and a tiny bit fast

Synopsis:
    find / -print0 | ./ownify -n 2>&1 | tee ownify.log

Input:
    reads a null-delimited stream of file specifications from the
    standard input; 

Options:
    -n/--dry-run    - test run (no changes)

Exit code:
    number of failed items
```

Comment: While interesting, I didn't do it in C because I'm running this against about 5,000 machines which are a mix of three AIX releases on PPC, three HP-UX releases each on both PA-RISC and IA64, and four Linux releases on x86, ia64, em64t, ppc, and zOS.  The time it'd take to get thing thing compiled across every platform far outweighs the really minor performance increase in a program which is very heavily disk IO-bound.

Comment: And, as I mentioned, I can't "just" do a stream because, if this breaks then I have to be able to resume.  In some cases I have a single directory which contains literally billions of files - just the one directory is what blows the memory limits.  If the directory contains the case where a->b and b->a, then if I'm partway through, I'm screwed unless I've kept a log of what's changed.  The only way to be absolutely sure that the log is consistent is to pre-create the log, and not start my changes until the log is written to disk.  And then I'm back where I started. :D

Comment: Oh, and solaris.  I always forget about slowlaris. :)

Comment: The nice thing about C is that I could get access to the AIX system call which changes ownership on a symlink.  While purely cosmetic, I had to write some code in perl which creates a temp directory owned by the new user, forks a child process which switches to the temp dir and drops privs to the new user/group before creating the new symlink, then in the parent, when the child exits, moves the new link on top of the old one.  It's such an ugly hack, but the only way I can "change ownership" on a symlink on most platforms. :/  But it has to be done, or users will freak out at the numeric ids.

Comment: Added explanation of 'streaming' idea with perl examples, see top of post

Comment: I have a Computer Engineering background, actually.  Creating a hash is done by using a hashing algorithm to identify a "bucket" where the element should be inserted, and then doing a linear search within that bucket to identify if the element exists there or not.  Assuming an efficient hashing algorithm (which is accurate), this is way faster than most sort implementations - particularly given the I/O overhead incurred by running the sort command against a data source in a file.  So it's not contradictory.  Try it and see the performance difference. :)

Comment: The idea of generating a shell script is interesting.  However, there are two difficulties with that.  One is that a million-line script will be really slow.  Not so much for parsing, since it's only read once top-to-bottom.  But it'd be atrocious because you'd be launching a new chown command for every file.  That's a *ton* of fork/exec calls.  And you have the complexity of having to worry about quoting the command line arguments.  But it's the right idea: instead of keeping the change list in memory, doing it in a file.  I appreciate the dialogue, so keep it coming. :)

Comment: In your stat() call, it'll be faster (due to fewer variable assignments) if you use an array slice rather than keeping all of the elements.  Ie, do ($dev,$inode,$mode,$uid,$gid) = (stat)[0,1,2,4,5];  Also, you want to declare the variables w/ my outside of the while loop.  Putting the "my" inside the while means that each variable is removed and recreated when they go out of scope, which is once per iteration.  Moving them up a scope level saves significant variable allocation time. :)  Well, it's significant in a tight loop like this, anyway.

Comment: re hash: it's not the sort efficiency; it's about the storage requirements, re stat: it's gonna be disk bound (you worry about storing a dozen integers, instead of the full hashtable?);  On the subject: yes I fully agree that you _should_ optimize this for fork/exec minizations (not so much the parsing because it will be negligable _and_ it is again in streaming mode); However, I've insufficient insight in your problem domain to 'guess' what kind of optimizations could be grouped. So, at this point: good luck!

Comment: PS: quick win: generate a perl script to do the chmods, directly (perhaps as an include to an OS-specific template chmod.pl); that way, the fork/exec overhead is pretty much gone

Answer (score 0):

A few possible solutions that come to mind:

1) Do not store a *hash* in the file, just a sorted list in any format that can be reasonably parsed serially. By sorting the list by filename, you should get the equivalent of running `find` again, without actually doing it:

```
# UID, GID, MODE, Filename
0,0,600,/a/b/c/d/e
1,1,777,/a/b/c/f/g
...
```

Since the list is sorted by filename, the contents of each directory should be bunched together in the file. You do not have to use Perl to sort the file, `sort` will do nicely in most cases.

You can then just read in the file line-by-line - or with any delimiter that will not mangle your filenames - and just perform any changes. Assuming that you can tell which changes are needed for each file at once, it does not sound as if you actually need the random-access capabilities of a hash, so this should do.

So the process would happen in three steps:

- Create the change file
- Sort the change file
- Perform changes per the change file

2) If you cannot tell which changes each file needs at once, you could have multiple lines for each file, each detailing a part of the changes. Each line would be produced the moment you determine a needed change at the first step. You can then merge them after sorting.

3) If you *do* need random access capabilities, consider using a proper embedded database, such as BerkeleyDB or SQLite. There are Perl modules for most embedded databases around. This will not be quite as fast, though.

Comment: #1 is sort of what I'm doing now, just harder to work with.  I freeze() the hash to a file, which has the benefit of not requiring any special characters or other nonsense.  And I don't need to sort a list which will literally contain billions of items; the process already takes over an hour in some situations - and that's downtime, because I can't have processes running at time when I'm changing UIDs/GIDs, as the processes may either create new files or fail to access existing files and blow up in unpredictable ways. :/

Comment: Along the path you're trying to go, though, I'm considering tie-ing the hash to a DBM file so that the database isn't stored in-memory.  The difficulty with that is that tie'd structures don't do well with many levels of references, and I make fairly heavy use of references specifically to improve memory consumption issues.  Using a disk-based datastore would also add a huge performance penalty, which I already can't afford.  SQLite, from what I've read, is pretty bad for things I want to go fast.  And I'd have to compile it on 25+ platforms, which is no fun. ;)